How to find indexes of similar values for each row in a Nx2 array?
Suppose a continuous variable A is changing slowly across time, its value and noise are logged in each row of a Nx2 array, how to find the values that belong to A from each row?
We can assume that A does not change very quickly, which means the values of A in two adjacent rows are much closer to each other than they are to the noises.
For example,   matrix = [[-7, 3],[3.9, 8],[-3, 5.5],[5.2, 10]]   , the expected indexes are [1,0,1,0], which refers to [3, 3.9, 5.5, 5.2] that belongs to A.
Thanks in advance!

Can you clarify how this is being calculated? Do you just want the index of the closer value in each iteration? That should go in an [edit], by the way.

@Anerdw thanks for the reminder, i edited the description, i do want the index of the closer value between rows, like [3, 3.9, 5.5, 5.2] in the given example.


I assume that you know the A_position in the first row.
Then just find the min value in abs differences in each for-loop.

import numpy as np

def find_continuous_variable(matrix,A_pos):
    data = np.array(matrix)
    indexes = []
    current_A = data[0, A_pos] 
    
    for row in data:
        differences = np.abs(row - current_A)
        min_index = np.argmin(differences)
        indexes.append(min_index)
        current_A = row[min_index]
    
    return indexes


matrix = [[-7, 3, 5], [3.9, 8, 6], [-3, 5.5, 0], [5.2, 10, 4]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix,1)
print(result)
# [1, 0, 1, 0]
matrix = [[-7, 3], [3.9, 8], [-3, 5.5], [5.2, 10]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix,1)
print(result)
# [1, 0, 1, 0]



If you don't know the exactly index of A in the first row, then just guess which one is the best index.

import numpy as np

def find_continuous_variable(matrix):
    data = np.array(matrix)
    
    min_total_dif = 10**10
    min_ans = []

    for initial_index in range(len(data[0])):
        now_total_dif = 0
        current_A = data[0, initial_index] 
        indexes = []
        
        for row in data:
            differences = np.abs(row - current_A)
            min_index = np.argmin(differences)
            now_total_dif += np.min(differences)
            indexes.append(min_index)
            current_A = row[min_index]

        if now_total_dif<min_total_dif:
            min_total_dif = now_total_dif
            min_ans = indexes

    return min_ans


matrix = [[-7, 3, 5], [3.9, 8, 6], [-3, 5.5, 0], [5.2, 10, 4]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix)
print(result)
# [2, 2, 1, 0], since [5,6,5.5,5.2] is a better answer than [3, 3.9, 5.5, 5.2]
matrix = [[-7, 3], [3.9, 8], [-3, 5.5], [5.2, 10]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix)
print(result)
# [1, 0, 1, 0]



If you care the performance and don't want the nested loop, such as only use first two or some row to "guess" the initial_index of A, depends on your data pattern. This is an example code to make it fast.

import numpy as np

def find_continuous_variable(matrix):
    data = np.array(matrix)
    indexes = []
    initial_diffs = np.abs(data[1] - data[0])
    initial_index = np.argmin(initial_diffs)
    current_A = data[0, initial_index] 
    
    for row in data:
        differences = np.abs(row - current_A)
        min_index = np.argmin(differences)
        indexes.append(min_index)
        current_A = row[min_index]
    
    return indexes

matrix = [[-7, 3, 5], [3.9, 8, 6], [-3, 5.5, 0], [5.2, 10, 4]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix)
print(result)
# [2, 2, 1, 0], since [5,6,5.5,5.2] is a better answer than [3, 3.9, 5.5, 5.2]
matrix = [[-7, 3], [3.9, 8], [-3, 5.5], [5.2, 10]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix)
print(result)
# [1, 0, 1, 0]


EDIT：If your data is always an Nx2 array, simply run the first function twice with A_pos set to 0 and 1.

thanks for the reply,  in my case, i don't know the A position in the first row

@Jeema no problem, I updated my answer to guess the A position in the first row.

great, it seems to be what i'm looking for, one small question, is it possible to replace the two for loop with matrix calculation?

@Jemma It depends on your data, as I don't know your data exact pattern, the best I can do is providing an idea. I'll update it.

@Jemma If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted and upvoting it to acknowledge the effort. Thank you!

Yea, i'll do that, thanks a lot,  i posted another answer, seems to work too, I would appreciate your feedback on it.

Another solution, seems to work too, for your reference.
def find_continuous_variable(matrix):
    data = np.array(matrix)
    assert data.shape[1]==2

    dp = np.zeros_like(data)
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        dp[i, 0] = min(dp[i-1, 0] + abs(data[i, 0] - data[i-1, 0]),
                    dp[i-1, 1] + abs(data[i, 0] - data[i-1, 1]))
        dp[i, 1] = min(dp[i-1, 0] + abs(data[i, 1] - data[i-1, 0]),
                    dp[i-1, 1] + abs(data[i, 1] - data[i-1, 1]))
    return np.argmin(dp, axis=1)

matrix = [[1, -2], [3.9, 8], [-3, 5.5], [5.2, 10]]
result = find_continuous_variable(matrix)
print(result) # [1, 0, 1, 0]

